# Mygene showing AttributeError even though code is identical to handbook

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I am trying to get the Entrezgene names for my RNA seq EdgeR output. I found mygene and thought I'd try it out, but regardless of what I do (have tried on home system and server), I get this error:

```
import mygene as mg
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("EdgeR-results.csv", header=0)
col_a = list(data.GeneID)
out = mg.querymany(col_a, scopes='ensembl.gene', fields='entrezgene', species='human')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'querymany'

Attempt with just a typed out list:

```
mg.getgenes(['ENSG00000176658.17','ENSG00000085224.22','ENSG00000112562.18','ENSG00000184347.14','ENSG00000183117.19','ENSG00000149218.5','ENSG00000123572.17','ENSG00000146938.16','ENSG00000206195.10'], fields="entrezgene")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getgenes'

I am at a loss. This code is straight out of several manuals and tutorials. Can anyone help me? I have thousands of ensemble gene IDs I need to convert and somehow merge back into my dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: Change `import mygene` to `import mygene as mg`? Or try `mygene.querymany`

Comment: Hi - I just realized that my code above has that error - I have tried so many variations of it, that I copy pasted it incorrectly.

Doing:
    import mygene
or:
    import mygene as mg
has no effect on the error message, nor does changing mg to mygene in the rest of the code with the appropriate name imported.

This problem persists and won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following before the query:

```
mg = mygene.MyGeneInfo()
```

I just came across the same error and found that snippet in someone else's example code. It resolved the error for me.